# Get time stamp of change in column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that tracks a certain status using a bit column.I want to get the first timestamp of the status change. I have got the desired output using temp table but is there a better way to do this?

I get the max time stamp for status 1, then I get the min timestamp for status 0 and if the min timestamp for status 0 is greater than max timestamp for status 1 then I include it in the result set.

Sample data

```
123 0   2016-12-21 20:04:56.217
123 0   2016-12-21 19:00:28.980
123 0   2016-12-21 17:00:10.207 <-- Get this record because this is the latest status change from 1 to 0
123 1   2016-12-20 16:15:58.787
123 1   2016-12-20 16:11:36.523
123 1   2016-12-20 14:20:02.467
123 1   2016-12-20 13:57:57.623
123 0   2016-12-20 13:55:31.421 <-- This should not be included in the result even though it is a status change but since it is not the latest
123 1   2016-12-20 13:54:57.307
123 0   2016-12-19 12:23:46.103
123 0   2016-12-18 11:47:21.267
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_status_changed
(
   id VARCHAR(22) NOT NULL,
   enabled BIT NOT NULL,
   dt_create DATETIME NOT null
)
INSERT INTO #temp_status_changed
SELECT id,enabled,MAX(dt_create) FROM mytable WHERE enabled=1 
GROUP BY id,enabled

SELECT a.id,a.enabled,MIN(a.dt_create)  FROM mytable a 
JOIN #temp_status_changed b ON a.id=b.id
WHERE a.enabled=0 
GROUP BY a.id,a.enabled 
HAVING MIN(a.dt_create) > (SELECT dt_create FROM #temp_status_changed WHERE id=a.id)


DROP TABLE #temp_status_changed
```

Comment: Do you also want the first record where the status = 1 or only 0?

Comment: Is it always 1->0 or do those numbers vary?

Comment: @Siyual Only 0.

Comment: @AaronDietz Its a bit column so 1,0 thats it.

Comment: I'm confused. Don't you just want the earliest date which has a status of 0? I.e. a simple select statement.

Comment: No because it doesn't reflect the latest change from 1 to 0.

Comment: It's clearer now that you've added more rows, showing that the status changes more than once ;)

Comment: @AndyG Sorry should have done that before,I got downvoted :(

Comment: Now you are upvoted ;)

Comment: I upvoted your post since I knew what you were trying to do. Don't feel bad :-) I think the answer below from @Nenad Zivkovic is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Isaiah3015 LAG() is cool but Nenad answer will include a row everytime a status was changed from 1 to 0.Thanks for the upvote, helped me jump over 5K in rep :-)

Comment: this is a beautiful logic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve that.

For example, using [LAG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function you can always get the previous value and compare it:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *, LAG(Enabled) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt_create) PrevEnabled 
    FROM YourTable
) x
WHERE Enabled = 0 AND PrevEnabled = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.What I am looking for is just 1 row which is the latest status change from 1 to 0.Your answer gives me a row for every status change from 1 to 0.Thanks for pointing me to LAG(), pretty neat function.Also,Partitioning  is very slow.I have a table with 370+ million rows and it takes 7+ mins while the one I have with temp table takes 12 seconds.Is there a reason for it?

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Once  you have all changes, shouldn't be hard to filter last one.  As for performances, that can depend of a lot of things, like what kind of indexes you have on table, and how is your data distributed. e.g: Is there are only few changes 1>0 in thousands of rows, or does it switch every few rows. Given the new info of 370m rows and that you only need the last change, LAG() is definitely not a good idea, as it has to pass through all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach without window functions would be:

```
SELECT
    sc.id,
    sc.enabled,
    dt_create = MIN(sc.dt_create)
FROM
    YourTable AS sc
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            id,
            max_dt_create = MAX(dt_create)
        FROM
            YourTable
        WHERE
            enabled = 1
        GROUP BY
            id
    ) as MaxStatusChanges
    ON sc.id = MaxStatusChanges.id AND
       sc.dt_create > MaxStatusChanges.max_dt_create

GROUP BY
    sc.id,
    sc.enabled
```

The query returns no rows for an id if there's no rows with status 1 for that id, as well as if the most recent status for the id is 1. An unclustered index on `enabled` column with included `id` and `dt_create` columns could improve query performance.

Comment: It doesn't work ,because I am looking for the latest status change from 1 to 0 not the top 1 sorted asc

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the id column. I've corrected the query so that it now returns the latest status changes from 1 to 0 for each id. It doesn't use a temporary table in order to eliminate temporary table scans and to leverage indexes. I've tested it on 420 mil rows and with that index I managed to shorten the execution time from aprox. 8 minutes to 22 secs, whereas your solution with the temporary table took aprox. 30 min to execute on my dev machine.

Comment: This gives incorrect results because of this condition sc.dt_create > MaxStatusChanges.max_dt_create is incorrect.The condition  should be min(sc.dt_create) > MaxStatusChanges.max_dt_create but you cannot use aggregate function in ON clause.

Comment: I've fixed your answer SELECT
    sc.id,sc.enabled, dt_create = MIN(sc.dt_create),MaxStatusChanges.max_dt_create
FROM
    YourTable AS sc
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            id,
            max_dt_create = MAX(dt_create)
        FROM
            YourTable
        WHERE
            enabled = 1
        GROUP BY
            id
    ) as MaxStatusChanges
    ON sc.id = MaxStatusChanges.id 
GROUP BY
    sc.id,sc.enabled,MaxStatusChanges.max_dt_create
HAVING MIN(sc.dt_create) > MaxStatusChanges.max_dt_create

Comment: min(sc.dt_create) is in the select list of the query. I've tested it on a sample with 420 million rows and it returned the latest status changes as you specified. Have you tried the query? Does it solve your problem? Don't forget unclustered index.

Comment: You don't need that HAVING clause. MIN(sc.dt_create) in the select list does the trick.